# How do I deploy a Dynamic Web Application made with Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Good Afternoon,

I have followed these 2 tutorials on how to make a chat app and I've successfully got them to work.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/

I have my project running on

http://192.168.1.15:8080/clxxxii/

You can't see it of course because It's hosted on my local network.

I'm trying to follow these comments and host my project online without having use my IP address. I would like to access the chatroom without having to be connecting to my local network. So they host project online.

---

(this is an excerpt from a line of a comments between the author of the post and a user)

So this application works only if devices are on same network ? 
Right ?

If you host the project online, it works like whatsapp over internet.

So, if i host this project in a server, say example.com, then what would be the web socket addrs instead ""ws://192.168.0.102:8080/WebMobileGroupChatServer/chat?name=" . ?

It would be ws://example.com/chat?name=" .? (Assuming WebMobileGroupChatServer is home directory for example.com)

### (this is an excerpt from a line of a comments between the author of the post and a user)

So say for instance I have www.chittychatty.com.

In the tutorial it asks to write it like this

```
public static final String URL_WEBSOCKET = "ws://192.168.1.15:8080/clxxxii/chat?name=";
}

SO i need to change it to this. 

public static final String URL_WEBSOCKET = "ws://chittychatty.com:8080/clxxxii/chat?name=";
}
```

I'm actually really confused. I would like to run the project online so everyone can chat together, not just devices connected to my network.

I've figured out how to connect the .war file to TomCat 8. I can now access the webpage without having to start the server in Eclipse.

I'm sure i'm just 2 or 3 minor obvious steps away from the answer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to have a domain that you own.  You can't just type in any url you want and  hope it connects to your app.

Comment: I have a domain that I own. http://www.clxxxii.com ... I'm not able upload files on the site. I don't think I can edit the html ...

Comment: The server that serves that domain is a Tomcat or JBoss or some kind of server where you can deploy your java web app?

Comment: Ok, so put the app and contents into the directory that you want on your web server, and you also need to identify the actual IP, not the local IP. Then navigate to that IP and directory in your browser.

Comment: I'm using tomcat 8. Evan, I have exported the project into a war file. So by putting the app and contents into the directory, you mean put the war file in tomcat/webapps also, how do i identify the "actual ip",  sorry for the stupidd question but what "actual ip"to what server?

Comment: Well, your local network is something like 192.168..... but your actual iphone can be found by either contacting the company who hosts your server,  or using the correct terminal commands. I'm not a tomato guru, but in CentOS you use "ip addr" there should be something similar in tomcat 8

Comment: Meant ip, not iphone. Also, meant tomcat,  not tomato. In regards to my above comment.  That's what you get when typing on your phone.